# Dynamically Generate id, and assign to label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]'
  });
});

var unique_id=0;
$('#update').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#myText').val().length == 0) {
    alert('Are you Kidding ? ;)')
    return
  }
  unique_id++;
  $('#result').append('<li>' + '<input id="checkboxFourInput" type="checkbox" class="todo-item" /> <label for="checkboxFourInput"></label>' + $('#myText').val() + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove todo-item-del"></i>' + '</li>');
  // $('#myText').val("").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  // update value
  $('#myText').val('').change();
});

$('#myText').on("focus click", function() {
  $('#update').removeClass("gray_text");
  $('#update').addClass("show");
});
$('#edit').on('mouseup', function() {
  console.log($('#myText'));
  $('#myText').prop("disabled", false).focus().select();
});

$('#myText').on("focus click", function() {
  $('#update').removeClass("gray_text");
  $('#update').addClass("show");
})

$('.hide').on("click", function() {
  $('.hide').removeClass("show");
});

$('#result ').on('click', 'li .glyphicon-remove', function() {
  // alert('Clicked');
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```css
.editable_text{
  margin: 20px;
  /*padding: 15px;*/
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
ul#result{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#result li {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #555;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
#myText{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 40px;
  border: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  /*left: -16px;*/
  width: 100%;
  top: -40px;
}

.btns{
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.plus {
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.okay{
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: -2px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray_text{
  opacity: 0.2;
  color: #222;
}
.show{
  opacity: 1;
  color: blue;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#result label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #4AADF1;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
#result label:focus{
  background: #4AADF1;
}
#result label:after {
  opacity: 0.2;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 7px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/**
* Create the hover event of the tick
*/
#result label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/**
* Create the checkbox state for the tick
*/
#result input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
#result input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
  background: #4AADF1;
}
.todo-item-del{
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Google JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="editable_text">
    <div class="btns">
      <a id="edit" class="pull-left plus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to Add">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      </a>

      <a id="update" class="gray_text okay" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Click to Okay">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <input type='text'  id="myText" placeholder="Add new goals"/>
    <ul id="result"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi there,

I'm trying to implement a To-Do-List for my Admin Dashboard, where I got strucked up, in this I was appending a `li` in my  To-Do-List as an item, for the very first time its is working fine, am getting `checkbox` which is working too, but when am creating the second To-Do, it is getting error, and the check box isn't working.

here's the code which I was trying but dint get succeeded

`$('#result').append('<li>' + '<input "$(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id")+"_"+(unique_id))" type="checkbox" class="todo-item" /> <label for="(unique_id)"></label>' + $('#myText').val() + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove todo-item-del"></i>' + '</li>');`

following is the fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/cr3aL4x9/)

Answer (score 1):

2 issues:

- `id` for the checkbox needs to be based on `unique_id`
- `#result label { ...  top: 15px; ... }` is causing each checkbox to be fixed at the same y position.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]'
  });
});

var unique_id = 0;
$('#update').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#myText').val().length == 0) {
    alert('Are you Kidding ? ;)')
    return
  }
  unique_id++;
  $('#result').append('<li>' + '<input id="checkbox'+unique_id+'Input" type="checkbox" class="todo-item" /> <label for="checkbox'+unique_id+'Input"></label>' + $('#myText').val() + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove todo-item-del"></i>' + '</li>');
  // $('#myText').val("").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  // update value
  $('#myText').val('').change();
});

$('#myText').on("focus click", function() {
  $('#update').removeClass("gray_text");
  $('#update').addClass("show");
});
$('#edit').on('mouseup', function() {
  console.log($('#myText'));
  $('#myText').prop("disabled", false).focus().select();
});

$('#myText').on("focus click", function() {
  $('#update').removeClass("gray_text");
  $('#update').addClass("show");
})

$('.hide').on("click", function() {
  $('.hide').removeClass("show");
});

$('#result ').on('click', 'li .glyphicon-remove', function() {
  // alert('Clicked');
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```css
.editable_text {
  margin: 20px;
  /*padding: 15px;*/
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
ul#result {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#result li {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #555;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}
#myText {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 40px;
  border: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  /*left: -16px;*/
  width: 100%;
  top: -40px;
}
.btns {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.plus {
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.okay {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: -2px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gray_text {
  opacity: 0.2;
  color: #222;
}
.show {
  opacity: 1;
  color: blue;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#result label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  /*top: 15px;*/
  left: 15px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #4AADF1;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
#result label:focus {
  background: #4AADF1;
}
#result label:after {
  opacity: 0.2;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 7px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/**
* Create the hover event of the tick
*/

#result label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
/**
* Create the checkbox state for the tick
*/

#result input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
#result input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: #4AADF1;
}
.todo-item-del {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Google JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="editable_text">
    <div class="btns">
      <a id="edit" class="pull-left plus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to Add">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
      </a>

      <a id="update" class="gray_text okay" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Click to Okay">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <input type='text' id="myText" placeholder="Add new goals" />
    <ul id="result"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to create a unique id in JS is with the Date object and getTime() which returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

```
new Date().getTime(); // 1461348496454
```

However, it looks like this is not the reason the label/checkboxes appear to be missing. They are there; they're just all in the same spot because they are `position: absolute`. You just need to add `position: relative` to your `li`.

On a side note, I recommend using some type of client side templating for this kind of task. It will make it easier to spot problems and keep things clean. Handlebars may be overkill if you aren't doing this much on your site. You may want to look into Underscore for simple things like this. It would be a easy and quick to implement.

- http://underscorejs.org/#template
- Example:
  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2411-using-underscore-js-templates-to-render-html-partials.htm

You would only need to change a couple things to use underscore templates. First include underscore in your page, then add a script tag for the template partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"/>
<script type="text/template" class="template">
    <li>
        <input id="<%- uid %>" type="checkbox" class="todo-item">
        <label for="<%- uid %>"></label><%- labelText %><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove todo-item-del"></i>
    </li>
</script>
```

Change your click handler to construct a data object for the template and use the template to create your html string:

```
// _.template returns a function that is used to produce html string using whatever data you pass.
var todoTemplate = _.template( $( 'script.todoTemplate' ).html() );

$('#update').on('click', function() {
  var $myText, labelText, uid, templateData, html;
    $myText = $('#myText');
    labelText = $myText.val();
    if (labelText.length === 0) {
        alert('Are you Kidding ? ;)');
        return;
    }
    // create the unique id for the label
    uid = new Date().getTime();
    // create the template data object
    templateData = {
        uid: uid,
        labelText: labelText
    };
    // use your template function to produce the html string you will append
    html = todoTemplate(templateData);

    $('#result').append(html);

    // update value
    $myText.val('').change();
});
```

I've created a jsfiddle to test it out if you want to see a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/n7bwymno/1/